# Tractrix - velocity pointing to pulling point

Tags: classical-mechanics

It is said the tractrix is the curve described by a mass being pulled by a string, where the end of the string being pulled moves with constant speed, and the mass suffers a friction force. What is the physics explanation for why in the tractrix the velocity is always aligned with the string pulling the mass. Why if $h(t)=(h_x(t),h_y(t),h_z(t))$ is the position of the mass, and $j(t)$ is the position of the start of the string pulling the mass, then the velocity is always aligned with the string, that is $h'(t) = k (j(t) - h(t) )$ holds, where $k>0$ is some constant. Can this be derived by for instance stating the forces applied on the mass and then using $F = m a$ or some other physical argument ?

Comment: If the drag force is constant then add it to gravity (vectorially) and call it the total applied load. The solve this like an elastic pendulum. Like a pendulum if no force is _out of plane_ then the motion will be _in plane_ also.

Comment: As far as I understand, there is "no" gravity in tractrix like motion, or more precisely, the movement is taking place perpendicularly to gravity on a surface such that gravity is cancelled by the reaction from the surface.

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine it as you pulling your dog (object) with a rope (string), while walking on a straight line, but the dog don't want to follow where you are pulling him and just want to stay in place. As you move, the tension of the rope felt by the dog is always directed toward you, making the dog move slightly (but unwillingly) toward the direction of that tension.

Comment: I was looking for a more mathematical explanation. The one you gave just doesn't make it clear to me what is going on. In a pendulum there is also a string attached to a point, and the velocity is certainly not pointing to the tension from the string, so the key thing here is probably the interaction of the surface friction and the tension from the string..

Comment: I guess the mathematicians are just assuming a friction force that is sufficient to not cause inertial effect, as in the pendulum.

Comment: what do you mean by "inertial effect" in this context ?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Many thanks for the update, Miguel.  I am sorry, I misunderstood the description of the curve, which is misleading.  The "mass" has no inertia (now I understand what philip_0008 meant in his comment) and is pulled infinitessimally slowly.  So the "pulling" here is a "quasi-static" process, not a dynamic one.  Although there is a force, it is at all times balanced by the drag, so there is no acceleration, and F=ma cannot be applied.  There is also no velocity in the usual physical meaning of the term.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

The velocity of the pulled object (or of the pulled end of the string) does not necessarily have to be in the same direction as the string.  For example, the particle could be in circular motion.  So there is no point trying to prove  mathematically that velocity is in the direction of the string.  I suggest that you provide a reference for this claim.

Perhaps what you have read is that if the only force on the particle is the tension in the string (eg the particle moves on a frictionless horizontal plane), then the vector acceleration is always in the direction of the string, because that is the direction of the net force.  But if drag is included then this is not generally true either.

Comment: wikipedia on tractrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractrix: "At every moment, the thread will be tangent to the curve y = y(x) described by the object". Any other text that I've seen on the tractrix says the same. The velocity is also tangent to the curve, therefore for a tractrix the velocity is colinear with the thread.

Comment: "so there is no acceleration, and F=ma cannot be applied". I'm exactly trying to derive this curve as a physical system, so I'm not sure if the curve can be interpreted as a physical system or not (usually it is claimed that it can), but as a mathematical entity it does have acceleration, velocity and position. If the start point is $(x(0),y(0))=(a,0)$ and the pulling point moves in the Oy axis, then the velocity for a unit speed parametrization where s is the arc length is $(x'(s),y'(s)) = ( -e^{-(s/a)},  \sqrt{1 - e^{-(2s/a)}})$.

Comment: As s increases the x component of the velocity goes to zero, although it is never zero. Also, the velocity in the x direction has all derivatives non-zero. It is a quite interesting curve. Equation above referenced from "Geometry from a differentiable viewpoint", second edition, page 85, by John McCleary.

Comment: I think what you are asking for is a mathematical analysis of a mathematical curve, not the application of the principles of physics to a dynamical system.  Perhaps your question would be more appropriate in Mathematics SE?

Comment: Well, I have more or less understood the mathematical analysis, but it is said that this is problem is motivated by a specific physical system. When introducing the tractrix they always state that "In the presence of moderate friction on the surface of the table, it is reasonable to assume that the chain will be tangent to the trajectory of the pocket watch.", and then go on to derive the equation for the curve. I'm not convinced why it is reasonable to assume such a thing, that is, it is not obvious to me, so I would like to see a convincing physics argument for this claim.

Comment: Stating the vector equations of time for each force acting on the mass would be probably make it clear for me, but I've never seen that presented anywhere.

Comment: The physics motivation for the tractrix curve is merely an analogy.  Analogies break down at some point the deeper you examine them.  This analogy dispenses with inertia from the outset, and without inertia it is impossible to apply F=ma.  I think you are trying to push this analogy too far.   As I suggest, I think the "motion" here is quasi-static : it proceeds by a series of infinitessimal start-stop jerks.  It is then obvious that "motion" is always in the direction of the "pull".  I do not think any dynamical analysis is possible - ie one involving F, m, x and their time-derivatives.

Comment: Let me rephrase: there is an actual physical phenomenon which happens when you pull a watch over a table in the way already described. See for instance this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_DgCZAf6aA. Given that this is an actual physical phenomenon, not just a mind experiment, what is the physics analysis using Newtonian laws of physics of why the watch moves as it does ? Are you saying that it is not possible to do a dynamical analysis of this physical phenomenon ? If that is the case, is it related with dynamic friction behaving in a more complex way in this case ?